# Glassfish: exception trace cut

Tags: java, exception, glassfish

I have a Struts action calling a chain of 3 EJB calls: the first one calls the second, which calls the third.

The third EJB can throw a low-level **checked exception**, which the second EJB wraps in a **runtime exception** (`throw new RuntimeException(e);`), as it is simply unrecoverable.

Now all the Struts action gets is `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException` caused by `javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException`, the stack trace is cut after that (which means, having looked at `Throwable.printStackTrace()`, that the `TransactionRolledbackLocalException` has no cause set).

Can I force Glassfish (v. 2.1.1) somehow to imprint the cause into this exception, so I can have a meaningful trace? Perhaps not to throw `RuntimeException`, but something more elaborate?